# Transferring file using WCF

Tags: wcf, file-transfer

I'm trying to write a WCF service that allows PCs and Windows Mobiles to download certain files. For the PCs I used MTOM to stream the data to the clients but it seems that Windows Mobile does not support MTOM.
How can I implement a single service to download files?
The file sizes vary from 100KBs to 10MBs.

Answer (score 4):

At this time, DIME is still the way to go as there is no MTOM implementation for .NET CF.

**See also**:

- [Dime Buffered Upload](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/DimeBufferedUpload.aspx)
- [WSE 3.0 cannot be used with the Compact Framework 2.0 on Mobile 5.0 devices](http://realworldsa.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wse30compactframework20.htm)
- [Upload and download large files - Windows Mobile (Compact Framework) via Web Services (WCF, MTOM, WCE?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518796/upload-and-download-large-files-windows-mobile-compact-framework-via-web-serv)

Comment: You mean there is no way to implement a WCF service for downloading in both platforms? What if I use buffered transfer with BasicHttpBinding? Is it a good approach with the file sizes I mentioned?